# How to display Data in Two Date Ranges in SQL

Tags: sql, date, join

I am trying to develop a query that will display data in two different date ranges to show the difference in transactions in those two date ranges. Here is an example:

I have the following variables:

1. AccountNumber
2. AccountType
3. DateOpeningAcct
4. DollarValue

And here is my query:

```
    SELECT
    AccountNumber,
    AccountType,
    DateOpeningAcct,
    Sum(DollarValue) As DollarValue,
    Count(*) as ReccurrenceFirstPeriod,
    DATEADD(MONTH,1,'1/1/2010') AS [FirstPeriod]
    into #vg1
    from 
    dbo.vg
    where 
    DateOpeningAcct >= '6/1/2010'
    and type in (657, 787)
    group by 
    AccountNumber,
    AccountType,
    DateOpeningAcct
```

and my second query:

```
    SELECT
    AccountNumber,
    AccountType,
    DateOpeningAcct,
    Sum(DollarValue) As DollarValue,
    Count(*) as ReccurrenceSecondPeriod,
    DATEADD(MONTH,1,'4/1/2010') AS [SecondPeriod]
    into #vg2
    from 
    dbo.vg
    where 
    DateOpeningAcct >= '6/1/2010'
    and type in (657, 787)
    group by 
    AccountNumber,
    AccountType,
    DateOpeningAcct
```

and my join query:

```
    Select
    a.*,
    b.*
    From 
    #vg1 a
    Inner Join 
    #vg2 b
    on
    a.accountnumber = b.accountnumber
```

So the problem lies in the results. I get the same exact results for tables #vg1 and #vg2 even though I have specified different date ranges in the dateadd function. Anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

I'm aware that both tables have the same variables in them. I need to be able to compare those variables in two different time periods on a monthly basis, which I am unable to do. If you know how to solve this please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI you can edit your question

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (DATEADD is a product specific function.)

Comment: Both queries have exactly the same FROM and WHERE . So both return the same data, to which SELECT is applied, similar SELECT items will get exactly the same values.